# Sculpting: How to join two ends (threads) of the SAME mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, topology, dynamic-topology

Good day, lovely community of BSE!
I obstacle a problem when taught my cousin a sculpting.

I tried to make a knot, like a cup handle, using Snake Hook sculpting brush. But when I tried to join two this threads, they doesn't interact with each other and saved their topology.

I understand that I can add a ring mesh and join it with a main model, but what about this particular situation? **How to join two threads of one mesh?**

As an alternative way, I could make a hole in solid bulge, **is it possible without Boolean operations**, like using brushes only?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own experience, i dont think you could use any brush to 'stick' 2 ends together. I haven't tried any Sculpt Brush add-ons, but i dont think you could join these 2 without adding another mesh and add a boolean modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> , to go in *Edit Mode*. You have to delete some faces at both ends, then you have to connect both openings. Press <kbd>3</kbd>  to edit faces.

For that go in vertex selection mode with <kbd>1</kbd> and always select three vertex and press <kbd>F</kbd> to connect them.